# OpenMP parallel only one thread seems to run at a time

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I'm trying to parallelize the below for loop with OpenMP, however only one thread seems to be running at a time. I can tell this based on the below observations:

1. Normally when I have prints inside the loop, the output will be jumbled and lines will be mixed together, however here, all my outputs are printed cleanly, suggesting that only one thread is executing at a time.
2. There is some heavy dynamic programming computation going on inside the loop, however I only see CPU usage on one core in htop.
3. If I print the current thread number `omp_get_thread_num()` I only see one active thread at a time. e.g I see some iterations all from thread 4, then some iterations all from thread 3 and so on.

This only happens after a while. For the first few iterations, things seem to run in parallel.

I'm not sure if there is anything wrong with the code that prevents OpenMP from running two threads in parallel. Below is the for loop and the templates for the functions called inside it. The functions only work with what's passed into them and don't modify any other data structures.

I'm suspecting this may have something to do with the fact that I'm passing const references to things around, could that be the case?

```
    // variables
    string ref ; // read-only access
    vector<vector<Cluster>> _clusters(24) ;

    vector<Cluster> position_clusters = some_function() ;
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(24) schedule(dynamic, 10)
    for (int i = 0; i < position_clusters.size(); i++) {
        auto& pc = position_clusters[i] ;
        if (pc.size() < 2) {
            continue ;
        }
        vector<Cluster> type_clusters = type_cluster(pc);
        for (Cluster &tc : type_clusters) {
            if (tc.size() < 2) {
                continue ;
            }
            auto clusters = cluster_breakpoints(tc, 0.7) ; // dynamic programming
            for (const Cluster &c : clusters) {
                auto result = dynamic_programming(c, ref) ; // dynamic programming
                _clusters[omp_get_thread_num()].push_back(result);
            }
        }
    }

    // Templates:

    vector<Cluster> type_cluster(const Cluster &c) ;

    vector<Cluster> cluster_breakpoints(Cluster& cluster, float ratio) ;

    vector<Cluster> dynamic_programming(const Cluster& cluster, const string& ref) ;
```

Comment: Is a [simple OpenMP program](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/openmp-hello-world-program/) working fine on your system? If so, the only explanation is that there is no thread available when the parallel region is encountered.

Comment: OpenMP runs fine on this machine. However, here it always get stuck with one thread active (although all 24 threads are actually launched).

Comment: What does `omp_get_active_level()` (https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.1/openmpsu139.html#x178-2110003.2.20) give you for your code where you only see one thread active?  What are compiler options that you're using and what the compiler command lines that you're using?

Comment: Note the `push_back` on `_clusters` will cause the size to change and that size variable will likely be stored on the same cache line than other ones stored in the array. This likely results in false sharing. Besides this `dynamic_programming` may be a problem if memoization is used internally. Can you check the distribution of the work between threads? Does the problem still appear with `schedule(dynamic, 1)`?

Comment: @JérômeRichard This was indeed helpful. I think the `_clusters` vector may be the source of the problem.